# Why is this SKSpriteNode in a different position on my iPad vs Virtual Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, sprite-kit, skspritenode

This SKSpriteNode slightly changes position when I run my application on the simulator vs when I run it on my iPad

[Here is what it looks like in the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa3Zq.png)

[This is what it looks like on my Ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8vfM.jpg)

Why is the green line slightly higher on my iPad?

Here are my GameScene and GameViewController Files

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let ground = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 20.0))
    ground.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 32 * 16, self.frame.size.height / 20 * 0.5)
    addChild(ground)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}

import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

//! means were promising we will initialize "scene"
var scene: GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Configure the view
    let skView = view as! SKView
    //If finger is on iphone, you cant tap again
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    //Create and configure the scene
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    //present the scene
    skView.presentScene(scene)

}


override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .Landscape
    } else {
        return .Landscape
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

I have had this problem in other Games i am making, and have simplified it down to just this program. I have looked and tried everything online. Can someone please help me figure this out? Thanks

Comment: Also, changing the scale mode to .ResizeFill does not fix the problem. The app is Universal, for iPhone and iPad

Comment: are the resolutions the same for the simulator and your iPad?

Comment: How can i check this @LukePatterson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your iPad's model, and check the simulator model. compare resolutions [here](http://www.iosres.com/index-legacy.html).

You'll probably only have issues if you are running the app on a retina device vs non-retina. If this is the only situation in which you are encountering the problem. Perhaps just extend the height of the ground further.

EDIT from comment*
"If you making an application Universal you need to set scene size in the following manner: scene = GameScene(size:CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536)) If the app is universal you can't set the scene like this: scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size), otherwise your Node positions will be all sorts of messed up"

Comment: You first comment fixed my problem. If you making an application Universal you need to set scene size in the following manner:

    scene = GameScene(size:CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))


If the app is universal you can't set the scene like this: scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size), otherwise your Node positions will be all sorts of messed up